# Lists (itemize, enumerate) without \parshape

Tags: lists, parshape

AFAIU (reading `ltlists.dtx`), lists (itemize, enumerate) in `LaTeX` rely on \parshape. Is there an other way to get the same result without `\parshape`.

*Motivation:* `wrapfigure` and list environments badly interact together because both use `\parshape` AFAIU, so I'm looking for a replacement. I could use two `minipage`s but I'd like to know if something else is possible.

Comment: To a certain extent you can emulate them with `\leftskip`

Comment: I can't show you a 'released code' approach, but with the mechanisms in `l3galley` it's possible to decouple paragraph shape from lists (or other 'running' shapings) in a natural way. That's done not by using a different TeX primitive (not available!) but instead by building data structures which abstract the different concepts.

Comment: @JosephWright You mean I won't use wrapfig with those mechanisms?

Comment: @JosephWright: Is there released code now that can be used?

Answer (score 1):

Package `enumitem` has a diagram (must-see) in its documentation that shows all the margins defined for list environments, and allows you to redefine any of them. One of the most basic ways to redefine is

```
\usepackage{enumitem}

% \setlist[enumerate]{left= <labelindent> .. <leftmargin>]
%%% OR to set locally: %%%
% \begin{enumerate}[left= <labelindent> .. <leftmargin>]
% ...
% \end{enumerate}

%so for example
\setlist[enumerate]{left=\quad .. 2em]
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Please -- as usual here -- make your code snippet compilable for a fast proof and can you add an screenshot of your result to your answer?

Comment: `enumitem` relies on `\parshape`, too.